# Click event not working on Custom ListBox C#

Tags: c#, winforms

This is my implementation of the CustomListBox

```
class CustomListBox : UserControl
    {
        //Fields
        private Color borderColor = Color.MediumSlateBlue;
        private int borderSize = 1;


        //Items
        private ListBox Listb;

        //Properties
        [Category("Custom")]
        public Color BorderColor
        {
            get { return borderColor; }
            set
            {
                borderColor = value;
            }
        }

        [Category("Custom")]
        public int BorderSize
        {
            get { return borderSize; }
            set
            {
                borderSize = value;
                this.Padding = new Padding(borderSize);//Border Size
                AdjustListBoxDimensions();
            }
        }


        [Category("Custom")]
        public override Color BackColor
        {
            get { return base.BackColor; }
            set
            {
                this.Listb.BackColor = value;
                base.BackColor = value;
            }
        }


        public void Add(object item)
        {
            this.Listb.BeginUpdate();
            this.Listb.Items.Add(item);
            this.Listb.EndUpdate();
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            this.Listb.BeginUpdate();
            this.Listb.Items.Clear();
            this.Listb.EndUpdate();
        }

        public int SelectedIndex()
        {
            return this.Listb.SelectedIndex;
        }

        public object Item(int index)
        {
            return this.Listb.Items[index];
        }

        

        // List Properties
        public CustomListBox()
        {
            Listb = new ListBox();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // ListBox
            Listb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            Listb.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            Listb.Font = new Font("Cascadia Mono", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            Listb.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(249)))), ((int)(((byte)(249)))), ((int)(((byte)(249)))));
            Listb.FormattingEnabled = true;
            Listb.ItemHeight = 24;
            Listb.Location = new Point(0,0);
            Listb.Name = "CustomListBox";
            Listb.Size = new Size(235, 936);
            Listb.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(Listb_DrawItem);
            Listb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            Listb.BackColor = BackColor;

            Controls.Add(Listb);
            ResumeLayout();
            AdjustListBoxDimensions();

        }

        // Highlight event
        private void Listb_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            Color backgroundColor = Color.FromArgb(50, 50, 50);
            Color horizontalColor = Color.FromArgb(100, 100, 100);


            if (e.Index >= 0)
            {
                SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected) ? horizontalColor : backgroundColor);
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(sb, e.Bounds);
                string text = Listb.Items[e.Index].ToString();
                SolidBrush tb = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(text, e.Font, tb, Listb.GetItemRectangle(e.Index).Location);
            }
        }





        //Adjust Dimension (Still in test)
        private void AdjustListBoxDimensions()
        {
            Listb.Location = new Point()
            {
                X = this.Width - this.Padding.Right - Listb.Width,
                Y = Listb.Height
            };
        }

        // Draws the border
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            Graphics graph = e.Graphics;
            //Draw border
            using (Pen penBorder = new Pen(borderColor, borderSize))
            {
                penBorder.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset;
                graph.DrawRectangle(penBorder, 0, 0, this.Width - 0.5F, this.Height - 0.5F);
            }
        }




    }
```

In a form i created said control and did the click event and the problem rose from tring to do this: (MainLB -> name of control)

```
private void MainLB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string text = MainLB.Item(MainLB.SelectedIndex()).ToString();
        }
```

The MainLB_Click is not triggering!

When a click happens i think the custom controls handles it by thinking the click was at the  listbox inside.

Said that, my problem is that i don't know how to make the event click work.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: is this winforms?

Comment: how are you binding the event to `MainLB_Click`?

Comment: it is and the `private void MainLB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` is in the form not the custom defenition.
That first part of code is the CustomListBox and in the form i'm tring to run some code when i click the CustomListBox.

Comment: @DanielA.White what do you mean by "binding the event"?

Comment: @Filipe Somewhere in your code (usually in the code-behind file of a form), you should see a statement like this: `MainLB.Click = MainLB_Click;` (forgive me if the syntax/names are wrong, I'm writing this from my regrettably foggy memory).

Comment: @MikeHofer I'm sorry i still don't understand where should i put it...
i could do `if(MainLB.Click)MainLB_ClickI();` but...

Comment: What is `MainLB`? It's nowhere in your code. So, what have you posted it for? -- Do you have a Control named `MainLB` in your UserControl? Did you subscribe to this event? Did you set a breakpoint inside that event handler? What is relation of this object with the all the rest? Nothing uses `string text` etc. -- If `MainLB` is a ListBox, the Text of the current Item is `string text = MainLB.GetItemText(MainLB.SelectedItem)`

Comment: @Jimi MainLB is the name of the CustomListBox in the form. Yes. Don't know how to do it. Yes, didn't trigger. He is a CustomListBox made with the properties of the first code. The problem isn't in the `string text = MainLB.Item(MainLB.SelectedIndex()).ToString(); `.

Comment: If `MainLB` is the UserControl, are you clicking its surface or some other child Control? That ecent is raised only when you click the UC's surface -- That is a problem, because you're exposing an `Add()` method. An User could add a class object or a DataRowView or whatever else. You cannot get its Text with the code you have now. Unless you assume you'll always get strings as items. But you're not enforcing this

Comment: I suppose i'm clicking the list inside the custom control. So what should i do?

Comment: You have to raise the Click event of your UC when the Click event of the child ListBox is raised. I.e., call the UC's `OnClick()` method (you have to subscribe to the Click event of the child ListBox in your UC) -- You should bind the DataSource / DisplayMember / ValueMember etc

Comment: let me try it out, what should i write there then? something like `Listb.SelectedIndex = this.SelectedIndex();`

Comment: I don't know what that means. In your UC, subscribe to the Click event of the child ListBox. In the Click handler, call `OnClick(e)`, this raises the UC's Click event, so the code you have in the Form is called

Comment: I don't really see what i should do, i tried putting the overwrite in the Custom element but it didn't work. And in the form i don't know what to write. Try answering even if the code is vague.

Answer (score 0):

**I don't know what you are doing**, but I'm thinking about you're doing some things in **NET Windows Forms**:

Check Listbox events in the ***design editor*** maybe **you didn't add this event or mistyped the event name.**

Comment: i did, such as the MainLB_Click as a reference.